# how to use Base64 algo in application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i get Base64 algo. from Google than i convert that string by calling as follow... string convert in data but in UIImage View i got 0*0 what is problem...

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];

data = [self dataFromBase64EncodedString:@"aHR0cDovL3d3dy5uZHJvaWQzNjAuY29tL2dwcy91c2VyX3Bob3RvL25vaW1hZ2VfdG4uanBlZw=="];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

myImage.image = img;
```

Comment: That certainly looks like an awfully small image if it can fit in 30-40 bytes. Are you sure the base64 string is correct? Besides your first line of code is leaking.

Comment: Have you actually *implemented* the `dataFromBase64EncodedString:` method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your base 64 string translates to: http://www.ndroid360.com/gps/user_photo/noimage_tn.jpeg which is obviously not the binary data of the image, but the URL. First you should access that URL to retrieve the binary data. Try

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self dataFromBase64EncodedString:@"aHR0cDovL3d3dy5uZHJvaWQzNjAuY29tL2dwcy91c2VyX3Bob3RvL25vaW1hZ2VfdG4uanBlZw=="]];
NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: thank you buddy for ur rply my php developer make mistake... if insted of this url he convert image in string than i can get image this way...

Comment: hey how to get this is URL from BASE64 string (How to u know this is url data please tell me).dataFromBase64EncodedString Method`s return type is NSData.

Comment: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp Paste the text, click decode, click "Convert the source data" Or use this code: NSData *data = ...
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: thank you so much sir i got prob and solve it thanks lot for your guidance